# In Python PDB, how do I list the source code of a file other than the current file?

Tags: python, breakpoints, pdb

I need to set a breakpoint in a file other than the current file, but I don't want to quit out of pdb and go into my editor to find out what line number it should be on.

How do I list lines of source code in a file that is *not* the currently open file?

Comment: does putting a pdb.set_trace() inside the file you want to look at not work?

Comment: @RockAndRoleCoder I'd prefer not to edit the file itself -- at that point I might as well use print statements.

Comment: Is it more than one file you want to set this in?

Comment: @RockAndRoleCoder Yes, I want to set and remove breakpoints across multiple files quickly without having to use an IDE like PyCharm.

Comment: Why do you want these break points?  I assume you want to place certain conditions on them?  I'm still new obviously, so the more I can ask the better chance I contribute.

Comment: Some modules use a brief main.py that immediately calls methods in other modules. After I run "python -m pdb main.py" I also want to run "list other.py" to see where I need to set the breakpoint. I'm baffled PDB provides no way to do this!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible using only pdb, but it's also easy to get it to work following simple steps:

1. Get `rich` to highlight your code (take a look at https://pypi.org/project/rich/)
2. Use `inspect` to get source of any module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object that you can import (check https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#retrieving-source-code)
3. print what you want

Example:

```py
from inspect import getsourcelines

from rich import print

from some_py_file import something


if __name__ == '__main__':
    src = ''.join(getsourcelines(something)[0])
    print(src)
```

Above code is done in a python script, but you can do it inside a pdb session. It will print syntax highlighted and indented code.

Output:

[image]